# How to send a contact form via JSON:API?

Tags: entities, 9

What are the requirements for submitting the contact form using JSON:API?

I enabled the core Contacts module and set up a custom site-wide contact form.  I gave permission to anon + auth users to submit the form.

Next, I enabled JSON:API.  I can see the contact form at `/jsonapi/contact_form/contact_form`:

```
"data":[
   {
      "type":"contact_form--contact_form",
      "id":"d97e73f1-7d06-4bf0-b05b-1c654a659dfc",
      "links":{
         "self":{
            "href":"https://example.lndo.site/jsonapi/contact_form/contact_form/d97e73f1-7d06-4bf0-b05b-1c654a659dfc"
         }
      },
      "langcode":"ja",
      "status":true,
      "dependencies":[
         
      ],
      "drupal_internal__id":"example_support",
      "label":"Example Support",
      "recipients":[
         "support@example.com"
      ],
      "reply":"",
      "weight":0,
      "message":"Thank you for submitting.",
      "redirect":""
   }
],
```

But, what is the endpoint I need to POST to in order to submit this form?

I found [this issue about emails not getting sent when a contact form is submitted via REST](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2936644).

That issue suggests that the `/entity/contact_message` REST endpoint must be enabled to submit the contact form-- is this also true for JSON:API?

I'm confused because using JSON:API, I can submit nodes without enabling any REST endpoints by POSTing to `/jsonapi/node/content_type`.

Comment: json api is not dependent on rest endpoint, for almost every situations making a post request to `Entity_type/Bundle` will cause creation of new entity of that bundle, so If that does not work then maybe it is related to json api module but I think enabling a rest endpoint shouldn't help in this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a REST endpoint is required in this case because although contact forms are entities, contact form submissions are not entities unless you use the [Contact Storage](https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_storage) module.

However, given the [core issue with notifications not being sent](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2936644) and the [large number of RTBC and "Needs review" issues in the Contact Storage issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/contact_storage?categories=All) as of January 30, 2022, I decided to take a different approach.  If a user is upset and reaches out for support, it's especially terrible to have some bug cause their submission to go missing or the response to be late.

So I solved this using the [Webform REST](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rest) module:

1. Install the module.
2. Enable the **Webform submit** REST resource using REST UI module.
3. Create the webform.
4. Add code to the frontend app to submit the form.

I got this working in about an hour, and the only additional change I have had to make so far is to [patch Webform REST so that I can uninstall REST UI after enabling the endpoint](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rest/issues/3205459).